# Create a network bridge between two network adaptors

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a Network Bridge with Powershell, but there is no documentation on where to start.

Is it posible to create a network bridge with powershell between two network adapters on a Windows 10 machine?

Comment: I think the best way is to leverage this task to netsh have a look here https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc754586%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Let me look in to this. Thanks for helping me on the way.

Answer (score 10):

According to [Microsoft](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/93c29a6b-8f8e-4c96-b173-40ec7437d652/how-can-i-create-a-bridge-connection-with-cli-on-the-windows-10) (from June 2019 and still valid as of June 27, 2020):

> There is no supported way to programmatically create a bridge.
> Bridges can only be created through the GUI.

Also, [the link given in other answers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc754586(v=ws.10)#remarks-1) actually shows that `netsh` ***cannot*** be used (see the Remarks section):

> The **install** and **uninstall** commands are not supported in the
> **netsh bridge** context. Network Bridge can be set up or removed only
> through Network Connections.

The only supported commands are:

- `netsh bridge show adapter`
- `netsh bridge set adapter`

Just like the quote says, on Windows 10 Pro, `netsh bridge install` gives the message that @SalamiArmy posted:

> ```
> Not supported.
> Please go to the Network Connections folder to install.
> ```

Network Connections is the page where you can change adapter settings: `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections`.

Comment: Update from end of Oct 2020, this still remains the same status.

Comment: Is there any information available when Microsoft will finally make that possible, either in netsh or by offering a powershell commandlet? It really is a mess that the network bridging stuff is unscriptable in Wndows 10

Answer (score 2):

You can use the powershell commands for collecting adapter information such as `Get-NetAdapter` or `Get-NetIPConfiguration` found [here](http://www.itprotoday.com/management-mobility/powershell-netsh).  Once you have collected the information you need to set up the bridge, then you call `netsh bridge set ...` with your configuration preferences.  For more info on the netsh bridge command, look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc754586(v=ws.10))

Answer (score 1):

It can be done.  I've done it for 4 port NICs.  It's not a pretty solution but it works.
Think of the manual process you go through to create a NIC bridge.
You can replicate the GUI manipulation using "sendkeys".  (Like I said, it's not pretty.)  *One thing you should consider doing is locking the keyboard and mouse as you're creating the bridge.*  If the window focus is changed during the build, it will mess things up.
Additionally, I had to include a verification search at the end of the initial build process to confirm that all required NICs were added to the bridge.  If any weren't, I had to create another "Sendkey" routine to add the NICs individually.
Since I've never found another way to programmatically create a NIC bridge we're still using this process.

Comment: One last thing....  MSFT changed their Explorer functionality between versions 1809 and 1909.  The code is slightly different between the two to attain the same results.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done.

Entering the command "netsh bridge install ?" into Powershell:

Not supported.
Please go to the Network Connections folder to install.

EDIT: On Windows Server 2016 Core:

The following command was not found: bridge install ?

Comment: I'm still working on this. I'm using ProcMon to see what Windows does when you want to create a network bridge and I'm trying to engineer it to a script in powershell, C# or C++.

Comment: Oh ok. Kinda like this guy tried to do 7 years ago on ServerFault? https://serverfault.com/a/313970

Comment: Yes but I don't got a Hyper-V environment. I got Windows clients that I need to brigde. But the workflow is the same. I hope that I got a prototype next weekend.

Comment: HA! People are downvoting me without offering an answer of their own. If I'm wrong then prove me so.

Comment: @StuiterSlurf did you make any progrss in doing this? Thank you

Comment: @Erik I didn't achievet it. Microsoft doesn't provide an API for this part. I read about applications that could do it for you but it didn't gave any guarantees that it will keep working. If you really want to build it yourself, you can analyze what Windows does under the hood with procmon.exe so you see the steps you need to do to achieve that. The company I worked for didn't wanted to invest in this and they choose to do this always manually. If you know the awnser, please sharing is caring <3